# PolymerJS : Calling function on load in table element

Tags: polymer, ajaxform

I want to call the searchByID() when the table cell values are iteratively loaded:

Here is what I have already and I would like to search the DB and return the value for the ID. (This is done by my searchByID()) All i care about how it is rendered

Code snippet:

```
<template id="course-table-rows-template" repeat="{{item in response.entries}}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/#/course-details?lo_id={{item.id}}">{{item.id}}</a>
                        <form is="ajax-form" action="/add_to_wishlist?course_id={{item.id}}" method="get" id="add-course">
                            <button id="wishlist_add_button" on-click="{{handleWishlistClick}}">+ Wishlist</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                    <!--{{item.primary_category_id}}-->
                    <td>
                        <form is=""ajax-form" action="> How do I call the searchByID on load? I dont want to create a button and do an on click</form>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{item.primary_subcategory_id}}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
```

What I want to do: Use the item.primary_subcategory_id and query the DB, and put that value in the . 
LMK if you need more code for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to **domReady** event. It will be fired if all dom elements ready to query. More info about Polymer event you can check it at https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods